# Clipboard library for java desktop and android?

Tags: java, android, clipboard, desktop-application

Is there a library that manage the system clipboard, usable both in java (desktop) and android? If not, is there a way to manage them writing the code once? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For desktop, [java.awt.datatransfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/package-summary.html) contains all the classes you are looking for

For Android, [ClipboardManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html) has all the methods for clipboard management.

I hope this is what you're looking for. If you need some examples on how to use either one of them, feel free to ask.